# Override device-width

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to make it mobile friendly by including `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in my html.

Unfortunately I have an element that needs to be larger then the device width. I was going to use media queries to hard code values for this element on different screen sizes but it seems like I am not able to override the elements width.

This is the element whose width I want to override:

`<div id="menu_bar">`

Currently the only way I can override this elements width is by doing:

`<div id="menu_bar" style=" width: 1024px;">`

However if I do:

```
<style>
    #menu_bar {width : 1024px;}
</style>
<div id="menu_bar">
```

it does not work. Even adding `!important` does not work. I need to be able to do it the second way because I need to use media queries.

Just for reference I have the menu bar as a ruby on rails partial because on every page of my website.

Any idea how to override the width of the menu bar so I can use media queries?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried @media queries? Like  `@media (min-width: 1024px) {}` Where that would encapsulate everything at that specific width?

Comment: Yup I already tried adding a media query in my style and it didn't work. But the issues is (for my test device at least which is an iPhone) that the width is actually `320px` but I need to override my menu bar's width to be `1024px`so setting the media query width to `1024px` wont work.

Comment: Have you considered using a media query and having two navs, where one is hidden while the other is shown? Something like this: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRn8r/1/)

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/kRn8r/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try going to http://atmedia.info/ -- it will scan your device (refresh to rescan it in portrait and in landscape) - it tells you a bit about media queries that match your device. Assuming you have not already solved your stuff yet.

This meta tag combo seems to help me.. and I use media queries to match devices in min-width and min-height (max as well)

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="mobileoptimized" value="0" />
```